# jQuery, change status of links when another is clicked

Tags: jquery

I am working on a slideout menu and everything works perfectly, except, I would like when I click on a dropdown link, any other open link closes.  Here is the jQuery I am running to add a class to change the status of the dropdown:

```
(function ($) {
  'use strict';

  var defaults = {};

  function Sidenav (element, options) {
    this.$el = $(element);
    this.opt = $.extend(true, {}, defaults, options);

    this.init(this);
  }

  Sidenav.prototype = {
    init: function (self) {
      self.initToggle(self);
      self.initDropdown(self);
    },

    initToggle: function (self) {
      $(document).on('click', function (e) {
        var $target = $(e.target);

        if ($target.closest(self.$el.data('sidenav-toggle'))[0]) {
          self.$el.toggleClass('show');
          $('body').toggleClass('sidenav-no-scroll');

          self.toggleOverlay();

        } else if (!$target.closest(self.$el)[0]){
          self.$el.removeClass('show');
          $('body').removeClass('sidenav-no-scroll');

          self.hideOverlay();
        }
      });
    },

    initDropdown: function (self) {
      self.$el.on('click', '[data-sidenav-dropdown-toggle]', function (e) {
        var $this = $(this);

        $this
          .next('[data-sidenav-dropdown]')
          .slideToggle('fast');

        $this
          .toggleClass('show');

        e.preventDefault();
      });
    },

    toggleOverlay: function () {
      var $overlay = $('[data-sidenav-overlay]');

      if (!$overlay[0]) {
        $overlay = $('<div data-sidenav-overlay class="sidenav-overlay"/>');
        $('body').append($overlay);
      }

      $overlay.fadeToggle('fast');
    },

    hideOverlay: function () {
      $('[data-sidenav-overlay]').fadeOut('fast');
    }
  };

  $.fn.sidenav = function (options) {
    return this.each(function() {
      if (!$.data(this, 'sidenav')) {
        $.data(this, 'sidenav', new Sidenav(this, options));
      }
    });
  };
})(window.jQuery);
```

Currently, when a link with data-sidenav-dropdown is clicked, I am adding a class of "show" and that changes the display in css to "block".  I am not sure how to make an argument to remove the class of "show" from other open dropdown when the link is clicked.  I only want one open at a time.  Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get the siblings to work, but with this workaround I got it working. I changed $this to find the child ul element, and then used an argument to hide all of them on click.

That caused another little hiccup with the class "show" not going away on toggle, so I had to single it out as well to remove it on click.

```
initDropdown: function (self) {
      self.$el.on('click', '[data-sidenav-dropdown-toggle]', function (e) {
        var $this = $(this).parent().find('[data-sidenav-dropdown]');

        $('[data-sidenav-dropdown]').not($this).hide();
        $('.sidenav-link-title').not($this).removeClass('show');

        $this
        .slideToggle('fast');

        $this.parent()
        .toggleClass('show');

        e.preventDefault();
      });
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

We haven't seen your HTML, but assuming that your toggles are adjacent in the same container, you can remove the `.show` class from existing elements like such by using jQuery [`.siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/).

See the new commented line below:

```js
initDropdown: function(self) {
  self.$el.on('click', '[data-sidenav-dropdown-toggle]', function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);

    $this
      .next('[data-sidenav-dropdown]')
      .slideToggle('fast');

    $this
      .toggleClass('show')
      .siblings('.show').removeClass('show'); // remove class show from siblings with it

    e.preventDefault();
  });
},
```